# Why does my Java compiler force a default case in a complete switch statement?

Tags: java, enums, java-8, switch-statement

I just struggled over this code:

```
int convert(ChangeType changeType) {
  switch (changeType) {
    case CREATE:
      return 1;
    case MODIFY:
      return 2;
    case DELETE:
      return 3;
    default:
      throw new InternalError("changeType is null");
  }
}
```

And the corresponding enum:

```
public enum ChangeType {
  CREATE, MODIFY, DELETE;
}
```

I wondered: The default clause is obviously wrong, because it is meant to catch null, but null will call an NPE on line 2 of the listing.

But while experimenting, I found that removing the default case ends up in the compile error "missing return statement", but without adding more values to the enum this switch is "complete" and there is no such uncovered code path.

**Q:** So, is it really expected (as a user of this enum), that I add a default case which is actually a dead (and untestable) code path unless someone changes the enum?

Instead, I would even expect that code analyzers like Sonar warn if there is a complete switch *and* a default case.

PS: The code is only an example. I know there is `Enum.ordinal()` which replaces most of the above code

Comment: `The default clause is obviously wrong` : no. `because it is meant to catch null`: **no**

Comment: In case of default just return 0 or negative value.

Comment: for enum strictly iirc, java-12 will fix this, as no `default` would be needed

Comment: @specializt Read my text: if changeType is null, I get an NPE and the default case doesn't come to action

Comment: @Eugene I think that's incorrect. I believe it will only apply to switch expressions, not statements. "in the case of an enum switch **expression** that covers all known cases ..., a default clause can be inserted by the compiler" ([JEP 325](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325)) In this case, the OP could convert the statement to an expression quite easily though.

Comment: @Michael good point! thank u

Comment: @Eugene No worries. I was going to be pedantic about you saying "java-12 **will** fix this" (because it's released today) but it turns out you were right (later today, I suppose), so I had to be pedantic about something else

Comment: @Michael is there an award for pedantic of the day? :)

Comment: @DanielAlder of course you do - everything else would be a very weird language or VM bug. Default cases are **not** supposed to be entered for `null` values - ever ... and thats what we observe, its why NPEs even exist -- to halt or to indicate serious programming mistakes which can only be worked around with `try` and `catch`

Comment: @Lino : no, he didnt.

Answer (score 1):

The default case with an exception serves as helper in case you ever introduce new `ChangeType` value. Say you added fourth type `UPSERT`. This `switch` statement might be in multiple places in your code base which are only designed to handle `CREATE`, `MODIFY`, `DELETE` and don't expect new `UPSERT` value. The exception is a [fail-fast approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) that will immediately tell you that something went not as expected.

Comment: in java-12, this `default` would not be needed in case of enums

Comment: @Eugene still worth adding this superficial `default` with a `throw` if the code is to fail-fast. It just doesn't really make sense for a `null` which should be checked with precondition.

Comment: I can't understand why, I never liked this, never.

Comment: @Eugene : it is **never** _needed_. But it is usually considered bad practise to leave it out because default cases **will** reveal programming mistakes later on

Comment: @Eugene As clarified in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55239849/why-does-my-java-compiler-force-a-default-case-in-a-complete-switch-statement#comment97212795_55239849), Java 12 will eliminate the need for `default` with switch expressions only and in that case, there’s truly no need to add a `default`, as the compiler will precisely generate a fail-fast, throwing `default` branch. That would match the OP’s use case, when converting the code, as there *must* be a `return` or `throw` at the method end.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki your answer is correct regarding why a `default` is needed, however, the error message of the OP’s code example, `"changeType is null"` is indicating that the author had a different, wrong mindset.